# Nested properties in xacro

Tags: xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know you can nest xacro macros, but is it also possible to nest properties in xacro?

I'm trying something like this

`test.xacro` contains

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot
    xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro"
    name="test">

  <property name="foo" value="1.0"/>
  <property name="bar" value="${foo + 1.0}"/>

  <link name="test_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="${foo} ${bar} 0"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
</robot>
```

but the output of `rosrun xacro xacro.py test.xacro` gives me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
...
<robot name="test" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
<link name="test_link">
   <inertial>
      <origin xyz="1.0 ${foo + 1.0} 0"/>
   </inertial>
</link>
</robot>
```

note the not expanded contents of the `bar` property

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59849/nested-properties-in-xacro/) by [Ruben Smits](https://answers.ros.org/users/350/ruben-smits/) on ROS Answers with karma: 543 on 2013-04-02

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With pull request: https://github.com/ros/xacro/pull/40 this problem is solved with Indigo release. I have tested your code and it now generates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<!-- |    This document was autogenerated by xacro from test.xacro                     | -->
<!-- |    EDITING THIS FILE BY HAND IS NOT RECOMMENDED                                 | -->
<!-- =================================================================================== -->
<robot name="test" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">
  <link name="test_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="1.0 2.0 0"/>
    </inertial>
  </link>
</robot>
```

which is the expected result.

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3